# plugin Config wont load correctly

Tags: yaml, config, minecraft, bukkit

I'm running a two plugins on spigot 1.8.9 called minigameslib and openskywars. To set up the randomizing of chests its required to setup a config

```
# Just copy paste if you want more chests. The percentages must add up to 100!
config:
  enabled: true
  chests:
    chest1:
      items: 5*64;5*64;5*64;5*64;262*64;278*1;5*64%30
      percentage: 5
    chest2:
      items: 5*64;262*64;267*1
      percentage: 20
    chest3:
      items: 5*64;262*64
      percentage: 25
    chest4:
      items: 5*64
      percentage: 50
```

Thats the default config file. It's named chests.yml

I'm atttempting to change the file to contain the following:

```
# Just copy paste if you want more chests. The percentages must add up to 100!
config:
  enabled: true
  chests:
chest1:
  items:298*1;303*1;304*1;301*1;276*1;3*64;1*64;368*2;262*16;322*4;
  percentage: 4
chest2:
  items:298*1;315*1;300*1;317*1;367*1;3*64;1*64;322*4;364*12
  percentage: 4
chest3:
  items:298*1;299*1;312*1;305*1;272*1;1*64;79*1;261:3#ARROW_DAMAGE*1
  percentage: 4
chest4:
  items:298*1;307*1;308*1;309*1;272*1;3*64;261*1;364*12
  percentage: 4
chest5:
  items:298*1;311*1;316*1;313*1;283*1;1*64;326*1;262*16
  percentage: 4
chest6:
  items:302*1;315*1;312*1;301*1;272*1;33:5#KNOCKBACK*1
  percentage: 4
chest7:
  items:302*1;299*1;304*1;309*1;272*1;3*64;79*1;364*12
  percentage: 4
chest8:
  items:302*1;303*1;316*1;313*1;283*1;1*64;261:5#ARROW_DAMAGE*1;364*12
  percentage: 4
chest9:
  items:302*1;311*1;308*1;305*1;367*1;3*64;79*1;368*5;33:
  percentage: 4
chest10:
  items:302*1;307*1;300*1;317*1;276*1;1*64;326*1;262*16;364*12
  percentage: 4
chest11:
  items:306*1;299*1;316*1;309*1;283*1;3*64;322*4
  percentage: 4
chest12:
 items:306*1;307*1;308*1;301*1;272*1;3*64;262*16;261:1#ARROW_DAMAGE*1;364*12
  percentage: 4
chest13:
  items:306*1;303*1;312*1;313*1;276*1;1*64;326*1
  percentage: 4
chest14:
  items:306*1;315*1;304*1;305*1;367*1;3*64;368*1
  percentage: 4
chest15:
  items:306*1;311*1;300*1;317*1;272*1;322*4
  percentage: 4
chest16:
  items:310*1;307*1;316*1;301*1;276*1;261*1
  percentage: 4
chest17:
  items:310*1;311*1;304*1;309*1;272*1;3*64;261:1#ARROW_DAMAGE*1
  percentage: 4
chest18:
  items:310*1;315*1;312*1;305*1;283*1;262*16;322*4;364*12
  percentage: 4
chest19:
  items:310*1;303*1;308*1;317*1;367*1;3*64;79*1
  percentage: 4
chest20:
  items:310*1;299*1;300*1;313*1;272*1;1*64;364*12
  percentage: 4
chest21:
  items:314*1;303*1;312*1;317*1;367*1;3*64;368*2;33:5#KNOCKBACK*1;364*12
  percentage: 4
chest22:
  items:314*1;307*1;316*1;305*1;283*1;326*1;364*12
  percentage: 4
chest23:
  items:314*1;311*1;300*1;301*1;276*1;1*64;261:1#ARROW_DAMAGE*1
  percentage: 4
chest24:
  items:314*1;299*1;304*1;313*1;272*1;3*64;262*16;364*12
  percentage: 4
chest25:
  items:314*1;315*1;308*1;309*1;272*1;79*1;261*1;322*4
  percentage: 4
```

Im not sure if my syntax for yml files is wrong or the item ids are wrong. The enchanting ids are [Here](http://wiki.ess3.net/wiki/Enchantments), and the plugin page is [here](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/mglib-open-skywars/). The program resets back to the original config every time its run, making small changes and its fine. I would like to get this long list working if I can.

I hope you have more like than I do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A yaml file needs a space after the colon.
Also indentation is dictative for what object belongs to what.
You made chests a top level opbject

You have

```yaml
# Just copy paste if you want more chests. The percentages must add up to 100!
config:
  enabled: true
  chests:
chest1:
  items:298*1;303*1;304*1;301*1;276*1;3*64;1*64;368*2;262*16;322*4;
  percentage: 4
```

it should be

```yaml
# Just copy paste if you want more chests. The percentages must add up to 100!
# top level. no spaces
config:
# secondary, two spaces. Could also be one space. 
# All following secondary level elements need to have the equal amount of spaces
  enabled: true
# secondary two spaces
  chests:
# Tertiary: 4 spaces. All following tertiary elements under this secondary 
# element need to have 4 spaces.
    chest1:
# Quaternary element. 6 spaces. All following  quaternary elements under this
# tertiary element needs to have 6 spaces
# Also note the space after the colon: Yaml needs this to discern where the
# variable starts
      items: 298*1;303*1;304*1;301*1;276*1;3*64;1*64;368*2;262*16;322*4;
      percentage: 4
```

Without clarifying comments

```yaml
# Just copy paste if you want more chests. The percentages must add up to 100!
config:
  enabled: true

  chests:
    chest1:
      items: 298*1;303*1;304*1;301*1;276*1;3*64;1*64;368*2;262*16;322*4;
      percentage: 4
```

Comment: "Secondary," "tertiary," and "quaternary," while arguably not incorrect, nevertheless aren't YAML terminology, and will probably do more to confuse readers than help them. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: lol, i know, but how often do you get to use those words :-p. Feel free to edit the correct wording in if you feel like it

Comment: while this may be true for YAML when i make these changes the same problem persists. the program resets it to the default removing my changes. I do not have access to the code so i cannot change it. Do you thing anything else could be off with it? other than the spaces after ":"

Comment: the program. Define. Minecraft? Bukkit/spigot, the plugins? Something else?

Comment: also, are you using tabs in your edited yaml? tabs are not allowed. use spaces only

Comment: I'm only using spaces, I only wanted to know if my YAML syntax was wrong. but if i was doing something obviously wrong it would've been nice to have fixed.